# How to pass the selected values to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have a select form and i display the data from database,Whenever I select a value,i want to pass it to javascript but it pass the selected value to javascript,when i run this it shows window.location = '?action=suppliernetwork&supplier_id=undefined.thanks

HTML

```
 <select name="supplierselect" id="supplierselect" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;background-color:#C2FFC2;width:125px;"> 
        <option>--Select--</option> 
        <?php
   include(db.php)

    $sql=mysql_query("select * from supplier");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
     ?>
        <option value="1"><?php echo $row['supplier_id']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>


    </select>
```

javascript

```
$(function() {  //  document.ready
    $("#supplierselect").on("change", function() {
        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
        var supplier_id=$("#supplierselect"+ID).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "suppliernetwork/select.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                supplierselect: $(this).val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#display").html(data);
               window.location = '?action=suppliernetwork&supplier_id='+supplier_id+'';
                $("#flash").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var supplier_id=$("#supplierselect"+ID).val();` is `undefined` because it never matches any of your `<option>` elements for a couple of reasons:

1. You're not assigning any `id` to your `<option>` elements (e.g., `<option id="myid">...</option>`)
2. Your selector statement (`"#supplierselect"+ID`) expects a value that looks like `id="supplierselectmyid` if, for example, `ID == "myid"`
3. Calling `.val()` on either your `<select>` or `<option>` elements will return you the value assigned to the selected option's `value` attribute, not the text node from inside `<option></option>`

Either set the `value` attribute to `$row['supplier_id'];` or try `var supplier_id = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).text();`

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your code is that you have not set the id of the `<option>` tag. By selecting `id` is:

`#supplierselectsupplierselect`.

There is no object containing that `id`. What you need to do is use:

`$("#supplierselect").val();`.

Comment: Using OP's sample code, `$("#supplierselect").val();` would return `1`, not whatever value `$row['supplier_id']` is.

Comment: `value` attribute is not required in the `<option>` since its static. If that is not passed, then the value of `$row['supplier_id']` is retrieved.

Comment: Be that as it may, the OP has clearly provided a `value` so my comment stands.

Comment: Then its a issue with the logic there but not my analysis.